# What is the difference between "Configuration status" and "Root level" in log4j2

Tags: java, log4j2

Here is a simple configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="logs/app.log"
                 filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <Policies>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250 MB"/>
      </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Actually what is the purpose of `Configuration status="warn"` and `<Root level="error">`. How those level impact in log file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<Configuration status="warn">` is for Log4j internal events only.

`<Root level="error">` is configuration for the root logger, it will apply the `error` log level for all logs except the ones configured in separate Loggers (which you don't have in the above configuration).